# Gmail loses browser encryption after a while

Tags: firefox, security, browser, gmail, https

I'm using the latest version of Firefox on the latest version of OS X for reference. I've noticed that sometimes when I go back to my email tab and look in the location bar, Firefox says gmail is no longer encrypted. Clicking on the icon on the left of the bar says the same and that the connection may be eavesdropped on. I have HTTPS always on but this still happens. My questions are:

1. Why is this happening and can I stop it?
2. Can others on my network see the contents of my email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably saw was Firefox warning you that the connection is only partially encrypted after viewing external images or other external content in an email.

To stop it from happening open your mail settings when in Gmail and change External content to Ask before displaying external content and never allow it to load external content when it asks.

No one else on your network can see the contents of your email except the external content you view that isn't encrypted.

Comment: I was able to confirm that the Firefox page icon (immediately to the left of the URL) does go from the encrypted blue to non-encrypted grey consistently when I open an email and click display images.

Thanks for your help an explanation as to what goes on.